# Retrieving friends' status updates from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of friends' status updates for an app I'm making. I'm essentially looking for the data that's in NewsFeed on Facebook.com

I'm currently using the `/<user id>/home` endpoint, which does return friends' posts, but they are all shared links, not status updates. I'm specifically looking for status updates (in FB Graph terminology, the Post `status_type` would be `mobile_status_update`. Here's the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post/

I could do this with FQL, but that's being deprecated so I don't want to rely on it. Anyone know how I can do this with the Graph API?

I could first grab friend IDs and then query for the status updates of those friends, but this would give me statuses that are not of interest to the user. I want a list of new and meaningful status updates from a user's friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's no longer possible with Graph API v2.0 or upwards, because the friends permissions have been removed. It's no longer possible to request the `friends_status` permission which you'd need.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions